# Kafka in scenario with many devices/data consumers

Tags: apache-kafka

Currently evaluating Apache Kafka for a use case where we have (up to) several thousand devices that produce transactions - each one generating a response in the back-end. A response, which must go back to the originating device.

For subscriptions, then, it seems that we have the choice of either having a topic per device (awkward from a management standpoint), or a single topic for transaction responses, and then have each device pull down all data for that topic - including everything meant for everybody else (sub-optimal from a performance-standpoint).

Is there a way to have the brokers somehow filter the data in the polling process (on the Kafka side)? It seems to me that this would be a common requirement, but so far I haven't seen anything along those lines.

Comment: would 1 response be used by 1 consumer only ? or multiple consumers might use it ?

Comment: One - the response will be relevant only to the specific device that sent the original transaction.

Comment: so for a topic 1 producer and 1 consumer ?

Comment: Well, I suppose there could be a use case for analyzing historical transactions (the upstream data), but definitely only one consumer for the response.

Comment: Having one consumer per topic isn't how it should be used. The cost would be too high

Comment: I will relay your viewpoint to the powers that be. Thx :)

Comment: Can you send the response back via SMS or email or another directly addressable endpoint such  as a webhook? If so then a Kafka Connector for "pick your favorite protocol" would work. I do this with Mqtt and/or REST in my iot projects.

Comment: @Hans Jespersen - it sounds like we would need something like that - thx.